# Give conditions on the derivatives of $M(t,x)$ and $N(t,x)$ to find an integrating factor of the form $\mu(t+x^2)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm stuck at the exercise $9$ of my ODE list:

> Give conditions on the derivatives of $M(t,x)$ and $N(t,x)$ in $$M(t,x)+N(t,x)\cdot x'=0$$to find an integrating factor of the form $\mu(t+x^2)$.

This is what I've done so far:

> $M(t,x)+N(t,x)\cdot x'=0 \implies M(t,x)\cdot dt+N(t,x)\cdot dx=0$
>
> If my equation has an integrating factor $\mu(t+x^2),$ then
>
> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu(t+x^2) M(t,x))=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\mu(t+x^2) N(t,x))$$
>
> This is the same that
>
> $$M(t,x)\cdot\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}-N(t,x)\cdot\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial t}-\mu(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial t})=0$$
>
> But we know that $$\frac{\partial\mu (t+x^2)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}\cdot 2x$$
>
> And
>
> $$\frac{\partial\mu (t+x^2)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial t}$$
>
> So $$M(t,x)\cdot2x-N(t,x)-\mu\cdot(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial t})=0$$

Am I going the right way? Am I missing something? Because I don't know how to proceed from here.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mu$ is a real function so both $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial t}$ are $\mu'$ and we have
$$\mu'(M\cdot2x-N)-\mu\cdot(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x})=0$$
or
$$\dfrac{\mu'}{\mu}=\dfrac{M_x-N_t}{2xM-N}=p(z)$$
where $z=t+x^2$. Then the integrating factor is $\mu=e^{\int p(z)dz}$. This means that if
$$\dfrac{M_x-N_t}{2xM-N}$$
is a function of $t+x^2=z$, then $\mu(z)=e^{\int p(z)dz}$ is integrating factor of the equation.

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}\neq\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial t}$, so $\mu_x \neq \mu_t$

Comment: Is. $\mu$ is real function of one variable $\mu(z)$, we haven't $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial t}$. It is $\dfrac{d\mu}{dz}$ where $z=t+x^2$.

Comment: So what's the condition on the derivatives of M and N?